# Type counts of a Series with dtype object in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

How can we get frequency of different types of data in a series in an optimal way?

Example:

```
Series : [1,2,3],(3,4,5),[8,9],[7],(6,7),0.78
```

where type of the series is object

Output:

```
list : 3
tuple : 2
float : 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `apply(type)` to get the types and then call `series.value_counts()`:

```
l=[[1,2,3],(3,4,5),[8,9],[7],(6,7),0.78]
s=pd.Series(l)
```

---

```
s.apply(type).value_counts()
```

---

```
<class 'list'>     3
<class 'tuple'>    2
<class 'float'>    1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
temp = StringIO("""  
[1,2,3]
(3,4,5)
[8,9]
[7]
(6,7)
0.78""")

df = pd.read_csv(temp, sep='|', engine='python', header=None)
df[0].apply(lambda x: type(eval(x))).value_counts()
```

**Output**

```
<class 'list'>     3
<class 'tuple'>    2
<class 'float'>    1
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections  import defaultdict
import pandas as pd
res = defaultdict(int)
ser = pd.Series([[1,2,3],(3,4,5),[8,9],[7],(6,7),0.78])

for i in ser:
    res[type(i)]+=1

for k,v in res.items():
    print('{} {}'.format(k,v))
```

output

```
<class 'list'> 3
<class 'tuple'> 2
<class 'float'> 1
```